# Site in subfolder - all pages work except home

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

Our WordPress site is in a subfolder `/subwp/`, and all pages except the home page work. This is the root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subwp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subwp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When visiting the homepage (e.g. `http://example.com/`) I get the hosting providers default site ('this domain is hosted by xyz'). All other slugged pages work perfectly.

Just to make sure that the hosting provider is not somehow auto redirecting requests to `/`, I created a file named `index.php` with just 'blah' in it, to see if it would work then, and then if I visit `http://example.com`, I see the text 'blah' (and also all other pages display blah now :))

I'm kinda stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the WordPress subdirectory, or are you doing everything from the root `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you request the document root, the rule in `.htaccess` does not match and the request is not rewritten to the subdirectory. So the request falls through and whatever is the default response for the document root is served (eg. `/index.php` if it exists).

You need to add another directive to rewrite the homepage only.

(The first `RewriteRule` directive is not correct either.)

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subwp/

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Special case - rewrite requests for the homepage (which is also a directory) 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

Since you are using `RewriteBase` you can remove the `/subwp/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* strings (that's the whole point of using `RewriteBase`).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative... This was driving up the wall and the provided solution was not working.  Turned out my browser had cached a 301 error with forwarding to the WordPress folder version of the URL.  I cleared the cache and my problem was fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/268520)

Comment: This IS an alternate answer to the question in the post's title and does not require clarification from the asker.  I'm confused by the critique.